error funcion lambda aws procesando imagenes para guardar a S3
Estoy teniendo un error que no consigo resolver al enviar una imagen a través de postman a una api que he creado en AWS, la request la proceso en una función lambda y para leer el contenido de la imagen la decodifico en base64 para posteriormente guardarla en un bucket de s3 con el siguiente código:
def lambda_handler(event, context):    
    
img_data = base64.b64decode(event['body'])
  
    # Guarda la imagen en un archivo temporal
    aux_path = '/tmp/{}.jpg'.format(generate_unique_id())
    with open(aux_path, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(event['body'])
        
    # Sube la imagen a S3
    bucket = 'mys3'
    s3_key = '{}.jpg'.format(generate_unique_id())
    s3.upload_file(aux_path, bucket, s3_key)
    
    return {
        'statusCode': 200, 
        'body': json.dumps({'message': 'file saved successfully'}), 
        'headers': {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}
    }

El problema es que a la hora de decodificar la imagen me da el siguiente error:
raise ValueError('string argument should contain only ASCII characters')

En la configuración de la API he añadido como tipo de medios binarios / así que ahí no debe de estar el problema.
Alguna sugerencia ?
Muchas gracias
